data.table vs dplyr: apply function returning changing column names over groups
I want to apply a function (ratefunc()) to a grouped data frame which returns changing column names dependent on the result:
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table:::data.table(
  group=c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), 
  x=c(1:3, 6:8), 
  y=c(4:6, 9:11)
)

ratefunc <- function(data, x_col="x", y_col="y") {
  res <- sum(data[[x_col]] + data[[y_col]])
  if (res < 25) {
    return(
      data.frame(a=rep("a", nrow(data)))
    )
  } else {
    return(
      data.frame(b=rep("b", nrow(data)))
    )
  }
}

dplyr returns the desired result by

assigning a new column to each column name returned and
setting NA for the observation of the other groups

dt %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_modify(
    ~ratefunc(data=.)
  )

Console output:
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group a     b    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     a     NA   
2 A     a     NA   
3 A     a     NA   
4 B     NA    b    
5 B     NA    b    
6 B     NA    b    

data.table instead coerces the results into one column ignoring the differently named columns:
dt[
  ,
  ratefunc(
    data=.SD
  )
  ,
  by=group
]

Console output:
    group      a
   <char> <char>
1:      A      a
2:      A      a
3:      A      a
4:      B      b
5:      B      b
6:      B      b

How can I get the identical result as in dplyr when using data.table?
And how is the approach of selecting the data frame columns by column name in ratefunc() (i.e. x_col and y_col being string inputs) to be evaluated in contrast to selecting them directly (i.e. x_col and y_col as vector/column inputs)?

Your ratefunc is not something I would create. I would do something like this. This could be wrapped in a function if necessary.
dt[, tmp := fifelse(sum(Reduce(`+`, .SD)) < 25, "a", "b"), 
   by = group, .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
dt[, ind := .I]
dcast(dt, group + ind ~ tmp, value.var = "tmp")
#Key: <group, ind>
#    group   ind      a      b
#   <char> <int> <char> <char>
#1:      A     1      a   <NA>
#2:      A     2      a   <NA>
#3:      A     3      a   <NA>
#4:      B     4   <NA>      b
#5:      B     5   <NA>      b
#6:      B     6   <NA>      b

Edit adressing additional requirements from comments:
dt[, colnames := fifelse(sum(Reduce(`+`, .SD)) < 25, "col1", "col2"), 
   by = group, .SDcols = c("x", "y")]

dt[data.table(colnames = c("col1", "col2"),
              colvalues = c("a", "b")), 
   colvalues := i.colvalues, on = .(colnames)]

dt[, ind := .I]
dcast(dt, group + ind ~ colnames, value.var = "colvalues")
# Key: <group, ind>
#     group   ind   col1   col2
#    <char> <int> <char> <char>
# 1:      A     1      a   <NA>
# 2:      A     2      a   <NA>
# 3:      A     3      a   <NA>
# 4:      B     4   <NA>      b
# 5:      B     5   <NA>      b
# 6:      B     6   <NA>      b


Ok, interesting. How would you wrap it into a function? And would that function then be tailored to data.table and not applicaple when using dplyr?

The column names "a" and "b" are not explicitly defined in the dcast function. Instead, they are inferred from the unique values in the "tmp" column of the original data table, and the dcast function creates separate columns for each unique value found in "tmp". How would you dynamically assign new column names independent from the column values?

See edit. Yes, I use data.table for efficiency and this approach is tailored to data.table. It obviously won't work with dplyr.

Ok, seems to me like a trade off between: Efficiency = tailored to data.table vs. clean = modularized functions. Maybe adding the column name as a separate column to the output of ratefunc() (as a long format output) and applying dcast() to that could be a compromise.

I don't think it's a good idea to create a function for this problem but in case you believe the opposite, you will need to modify it (see end this answer):
Find a way to solve your problem below:
In case you would like to add the new columns to your dataset, use
dt[, a := if(sum(.SD) > 25L) "a", by=group, .SDcols=c("x", "y")][is.na(a), b := "b"]

or the function below (more dynamic/flexible):
ratefunc = function(dt, x_col="x", y_col="y", nm1, nm2, val1, val2) {
    dt[, (nm1) := if(sum(x_col, y_col) > 25L) val1, by=group, env=list(x_col=x_col, y_col=y_col, val1=I(val1))]
    dt[is.na(nm1), (nm2) := val2, env=list(nm1=nm1, val2=I(val2))][]  
}

ratefunc(dt=dt, nm1="a", nm2="b", val1="a", val2="b")

    group     x     y      a      b
   <char> <int> <int> <char> <char>
1:      A     1     4   <NA>      b
2:      A     2     5   <NA>      b
3:      A     3     6   <NA>      b
4:      B     6     9      a   <NA>
5:      B     7    10      a   <NA>
6:      B     8    11      a   <NA>

Otherwise, use:
dt[, if(sum(.SD) > 25) 
     .(a = rep("a", .N), b = NA_character_) 
     else 
     .(a = NA_character_, b = rep("b", .N)), 
   by = group, 
   .SDcols = c("x", "y")]

    group      a      b
   <char> <char> <char>
1:      A   <NA>      b
2:      A   <NA>      b
3:      A   <NA>      b
4:      B      a   <NA>
5:      B      a   <NA>
6:      B      a   <NA>

Find the modified version of your function below in case prefer to use it instead.
ratefunc <- function(data, x_col="x", y_col="y") {
  res <- sum(data[[x_col]] + data[[y_col]])
    if (res < 25) {
    return(
      list(a=rep("a", nrow(data)), b=NA_character_)     # modified line
    )
  } else {
    return(
      list(a = NA_character_, b=rep("b", nrow(data)))   # modified line
    )
  }
}

dt[, ratefunc(data=.SD), by=group]


See my comment on jay.sf answer, I explicitly would like to avoid a ratefunc() to consider all possible column outcomes and producing more NAs than result.

I don't understand what you want even after reading jay.sf's asnwer. What do you mean by all possible column outcomes and producing more NAs than result? Also, why did you create ratefunc() if you want to avoid it? Could you modify your post to better reflect your problem (by including what you mean in your comment)?

Thats a fast and readable approach! (up)

The column names possible in the minimal example shall not be exclusive but rather dynamic which is clearly stated in the question. You as well as jay.sf implicitly do this assumption since your code is not dynamic to column names other than "a" and "b". IF that modularized function ratefunc() is not the best way to go when working with data.table as pointed out by Roland, THEN it is worth thinking about integrating ratefunc() in the data.table sytnax in order to create a one step approach (rather than having a two step approach with a hard coded column name output).

Would you like the column value (not the column name) to be also dynamic (meaning "a" and "b" used in rep function)?

Yes, I kept the example as minimal as possible.

I made some changes to make the column names and values dynamic. Let me know if it solves your problem.

You can try a better ratefunc.
> ratefunc <- function(data, x_col="x", y_col="y") {
+   res <- sum(data[[x_col]] + data[[y_col]])
+   o <- t(array(, c(2L, nrow(data)), list(c('a', 'b'), NULL)))
+   if (res < 25) {
+       o[, 'a'] <- 'a'
+   } else {
+       o[, 'b'] <- 'b'
+   }
+   o |> as.data.frame()
+ }
> 
> dt[
+   ,
+   ratefunc(
+     data=.SD
+   )
+   ,
+   by=group
+ ]
    group      a      b
   <char> <char> <char>
1:      A      a   <NA>
2:      A      a   <NA>
3:      A      a   <NA>
4:      B   <NA>      b
5:      B   <NA>      b
6:      B   <NA>      b


Thought about this as well but I explicitly would like to avoid a ratefunc() to consider all possible column outcomes and producing more NAs than results.

@Cevior In OP you "want to apply a function (ratefunc())" and now you want to avoid it.

I think this is the way to go except I would use list instead array (sapply(c("a", "b"), \(.) rep(NA_character_, n), simplify = FALSE) or similiar.

Here is another approach:
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table:::data.table(
  group=c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), 
  x=c(1:3, 6:8), 
  y=c(4:6, 9:11)
)

ratefunc <- function(data, x_col="x", y_col="y") {
  DT <- copy(data) # avoid modifying dt
  DT[, c("a", "b") := .(
    fifelse(sum(.SD) < 25L, yes = "a", no = NA_character_),
    fifelse(sum(.SD) < 25L, yes = NA_character_, no = "b")
  ), .SDcols = c(x_col, y_col) , by = group][, c(x_col, y_col) := NULL]
}

resultDT <- ratefunc(dt, x_col="x", y_col="y")
resultDT[]


Alternative: directly applied to dt:
x_col <- "x"
y_col <- "y"

dt[, c("a", "b") := .(
  fifelse(sum(.SD) < 25L, yes = "a", no = NA_character_),
  fifelse(sum(.SD) < 25L, yes = NA_character_, no = "b")
), .SDcols = c(x_col, y_col) , by = group][, c(x_col, y_col) := NULL]


A benchmark (you might need to check how it scales with your data):
Unit: milliseconds
               expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
 B.ChristianKamgang  1.0797  1.0797  1.0797  1.0797  1.0797  1.0797     1
             Roland  4.5069  4.5069  4.5069  4.5069  4.5069  4.5069     1
             jay.sf 15.7749 15.7749 15.7749 15.7749 15.7749 15.7749     1
      ismirsehregal  1.5379  1.5379  1.5379  1.5379  1.5379  1.5379     1


library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

dt <- data.table:::data.table(
  group = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)),
  x = c(1:3, 6:8),
  y = c(4:6, 9:11)
)

dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)
dt4 <- copy(dt)

ratefunc_jay.sf <- function(data, x_col = "x", y_col = "y") {
  res <- sum(data[[x_col]] + data[[y_col]])
  o <- t(array(, c(2L, nrow(data)), list(c('a', 'b'), NULL)))
  if (res < 25) {
    o[, 'a'] <- 'a'
  } else {
    o[, 'b'] <- 'b'
  }
  o |> as.data.frame()
}

microbenchmark(
  B.ChristianKamgang = {
    res <- dt4[, if(sum(.SD) > 25) 
      .(a = rep("a", .N), b = NA_character_) 
      else 
        .(a = NA_character_, b = rep("b", .N)), 
      by = group, 
      .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
  },
  Roland = {
    dt1[, tmp := fifelse(sum(Reduce(`+`, .SD)) < 25, "a", "b"), by = group, .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
    dt1[, ind := .I]
    dcast(dt1, group + ind ~ tmp, value.var = "tmp")
  },
  jay.sf = {
    dt2[, ratefunc_jay.sf(data = .SD), by = group]
  },
  ismirsehregal = {
    dt3[, c("a", "b") := .(
      fifelse(sum(.SD) < 25L, yes = "a", no = NA_character_),
      fifelse(sum(.SD) < 25L, yes = NA_character_, no = "b")
    ), .SDcols = c("x", "y") , by = group][, c("x", "y") := NULL]
  },
  times = 1L
)


Please don't benchmark with tiny input.

Just added a note.
